# Input event in Vue is executed twice when calling a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I was performing a function where in a text field the barcode reader copies the code, but when it copies the code, it performs the function twice, I already tried copying the v-model in another variable and clear original variable but still the same, any ideas?

```
<v-text-field
      label="Product Code"
      v-model="product_entered.code_product"
      @input="findProduct"
      autofocus
      autocomplete="new"
      :maxlength="20"
      v-mask="'####################'"
      ></v-text-field>

<script>
findProduct: function() {
            console.log('someone here')
           axios
                .post('/api/product/find', this.product_entered)
                .then(response =>   {
                        this.products_order.push(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                })
        }
</script>
```

[image]

**Upgrade:**
I detect that when I manually write 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 a digit, it only does it once, when it reaches two digits or more, 10, 11, 12, 23, 343,4535 it does it twice,

Comment: You might try calling 'findProduct' on a 'change' event instead of an 'input' event.

Comment: but the @change event, I have to hit enter or get out of the field for it to run

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour probably due because v-model directive replace :value and @input (that you've already written). Try to replace v-model with :value like this:

```
<v-text-field
      label="Product Code"
      :value="product_entered.code_product"
      @input="findProduct"
      autofocus
      autocomplete="new"
      :maxlength="20"
      v-mask="'####################'"
      ></v-text-field>

<script>
findProduct: function(product_code) {
           this.product_entered.product_code = product_code;
           console.log('someone here')
           axios
                .post('/api/product/find', this.product_entered)
                .then(response =>   {
                        this.products_order.push(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                })
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PrimeVue, Inputs have emit that is triggered when input value changes. You can try using

```
        <v-text-field
          label="Product Code"
          v-model="product_entered.code_product"
          @update:modelValue="findProduct"
          autofocus
          autocomplete="new"
          :maxlength="20"
          v-mask="'####################'"
          ></v-text-field>
    
    <script>
    findProduct: function() {
                console.log('someone here')
               axios
                    .post('/api/product/find', this.product_entered)
                    .then(response =>   {
                            this.products_order.push(response.data.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.errored = true
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        this.loading = false;
                    })
            }
    </script>
```